# Como criar um arquivo .txt no Android e deixa-lo disponível para abrir em computadores?

Tags: android

Minha dúvida é em relação a como eu crio arquivos e pastas que possam ser visualizadas e acessadas em computadores posteriormente.
Em meu código no projeto tenho um método que cria um arquivo de texto.

```
public void criaArquivo() {
        File file = new File (Envoiment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory("/") + "/testes/TextoFiles.txt");
        FileOutputStream outputStream;

try {
        outputStream = new FileOutputStream (file);
        outputStream.write("string".getBytes());
        outputStream.close();
} catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Bom, até aqui tudo bem ele cria um arquivo .txt lá no

> /storage/emulated/0/testes/TextoFile.txt

Verifico isso usando meus gerenciadores de arquivos do meu Android. Acontece que quando abro no PC via USB, habilitando o MTP aparece todas as outras pastas que tem nesse diretório, o

> /storage/emulated/0/

menos o que acabei de criar. Por que?

Comment: Não aconteceu nenhum erro na escrita do arquivo?

Comment: Posso abri-lo pelo gerenciador de arquivos do meu celular. Abro no Leitor de HTML que o Android sugere abrir com

Answer (score 1):

Descobri o que estava faltando eu fazer, eu criava o arquivo, mas só isso não bastava, é preciso executar algumas linhas de código para fazer o sistema de arquivos dos sistemas operacionais reconhecer o arquivo recém criado. Outro fator importante é que se o arquivo foi criado enquanto o smartphone esta conectado em MTP no computador é necessário retira-lo e coloca-lo novamente para que o arquivo seja visto pelo Windows Explorer, por exemplo.
Eis o código complementar para o programa:

```
...
file.setExecutable(true);
file.setReadable(true);
file.setWritable(true);

MediaScannerConnection.scanFile(this, new String[{file.getAbsolutePath()}, null, null);
...
```